# How to add html table with values in qweb report from py odoo 10 / 11

Tags: html, render, odoo, qweb

I have dynamic values and base on that i want to show multiple html tables in qweb report.
I have py file from where i pass recordset in qweb xml file.
I want to add html table with database values in qweb from py file.

Comment: You can check format of sale order report. From there you can add multiple lines and all the lines are there in table format and after that for dynamic value, you can create py file as a parser who passes data to your report.

Comment: You need to read the docs `QWEB` Reports https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/reports.html and `QWEB` https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table class="table table-condensed" style="border: 3px solid Darkblue;
                                                                border-collapse: collapse;">
                <h3>Planning Menu</h3>
                <thead>
                    <tr style="background:#DCDCDC">
                        <th class="text-left">
                            <strong>Product Name</strong>
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left">
                            <strong>Source Location</strong>
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left">
                            <strong>Destination location</strong>
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left">
                            <strong>Quantity on Hand</strong>
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left">
                            <strong>Quantity</strong>
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left">
                            <strong>Unit Of masure</strong>
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-right">
                            <strong>Actual Quantity</strong>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="color: #D8F0DA
                            background: transparent">
                    <t t-foreach="doc.service_line" t-as="o">
                            <tr align="center" style="color:red;">
                                <td colspan="7">Service ID:<span t-field="o.service_type_id"/></td>
                            </tr>


                        <!--<p><span t-field="o.service_type_id"/> </p>-->
                        <tr t-foreach="o.product_line" t-as="l">
                            <td class="text-left">
                                <span t-field="l.product_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                <span t-field="l.default_location_src_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                <span t-field="l.default_location_dest_id"/>

                            </td>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                <span t-field="l.qty_available"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                <span t-field="l.qty"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.uom_id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.actual"/>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </t>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```